# Concat array list in Apache Spark only if a column has a value over a window of partition account_id

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have below data:

```
+----------+----------+----------------+---------+
|account_id|batch_date|list_of_opp_acct|diff_days|
+----------+----------+----------------+---------+
|         1|2024-02-22|    [opp1, opp2]|        0|
|         1|2024-02-21|    [opp3, opp2]|        1|
|         1|2024-02-21|    [opp3, opp1]|        1|
|         1|2024-02-14|    [opp3, opp1]|        8|
|         1|2024-02-13|    [opp3, opp1]|        9|
|         1|2024-01-11|    [opp3, opp1]|       42|
|         2|2024-02-22|    [opp1, opp2]|        0|
|         2|2024-02-21|    [opp3, opp2]|        1|
|         2|2024-02-21|    [opp3, opp1]|        1|
|         2|2024-02-14|    [opp3, opp1]|        8|
|         2|2024-02-13|    [opp3, opp1]|        9|
|         2|2024-01-11|    [opp3, opp1]|       42|
+----------+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Now I want to group data based of account_id and diff_days less than.

Like I need `list_of_opp_acct` columns to be concatinated (or union) for multiple conditions. Like diff_days between 0 and 1(inclusive), between 2 and 9(inclusive) and greater (equal to) 9.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("SparkDatasetExample")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        // Sample data
        List<Row> rowDataList = Arrays.asList(
                RowFactory.create("1", "2024-02-22", Arrays.asList("opp1", "opp2")),
                RowFactory.create("1", "2024-02-21", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp2")),
                RowFactory.create("1", "2024-02-21", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("1", "2024-02-14", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("1", "2024-02-13", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("1", "2024-01-11", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("2", "2024-02-22", Arrays.asList("opp1", "opp2")),
                RowFactory.create("2", "2024-02-21", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp2")),
                RowFactory.create("2", "2024-02-21", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("2", "2024-02-14", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("2", "2024-02-13", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1")),
                RowFactory.create("2", "2024-01-11", Arrays.asList("opp3", "opp1"))
        );

        // Define the schema using StructType
        StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
                DataTypes.createStructField("account_id", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("batch_date", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("list_of_opp_acct", DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType), false)
        });

        // Create a DataFrame from the sample data and schema
        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.createDataFrame(rowDataList, schema);

        dataset = dataset.withColumn("diff_days", functions.datediff(functions.current_date(), functions.to_date(dataset.col("batch_date"))));

        dataset.show();

        dataset = dataset.withColumn("list_of_opp_acct_leq_1_day", concat(when(col("diff_days").leq(0), col("list_of_opp_acct")).over(Window.partitionBy(col("account_id")))));

        // Show the initial DataFrame
        System.out.println("Initial DataFrame:");
        dataset.show();

        // Perform any transformations or operations as needed

        // Show the final DataFrame with the desired columns
        Dataset<Row> result = dataset.select("account_id", "batch_date", "list_of_opp_acct");
        System.out.println("Final DataFrame:");
        result.show();
```

Code Repo: https://github.com/shah-smit/spark-spring-boot-demo

Comment: Show an example, poorly explained.